# Can I send pushes From FCM from self hosted parse?

Tags: android, parsing

I have tried setting senderid and server key in parse configuration where we shold put GCM credentials but it does not work, has anyone tried this yet?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that sending fcm message is exactly the same as gcm. As long as you have fcm serverApiKey and senderId from firebase console you are set. Setup push on Android for parse-server just like you would regularly and make sure you add

```
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id"
        android:value="id:senderId" />
```

in manifest and note that gcm_sender_id is the same as fcm senderId

Comment: So you are saying that you didn't change anything on parse-server configuration other than apiKey and senderId? How can it not give you 401 unauthorized if you try to call GCM URL with FCM authentication.

Comment: That's right. I just placed in the serverApiKey and senderId that was generated from the Firebase console. I don't understand the downvote, I presented what worked for me.